# How can I send to multiple Contact Form 7 recipients based on form input?

Tags: hooks, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

We are running a competition whereby we need to send emails out to email addresses that are entered on a form.  I'm using Contact Form 7 to do this.

I thought this would be straightforward but the form will not accept the syntax of:

```
[friend1-email], [friend2-email], [friend3-email], [friend4-email], [friend5-email]
```

In the To or Bcc field.

I think the solution might be to just hard-code a value in the To field and then override it with a hook, but I can't work out what that filter/hook might be.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to write any code, Contact form 7 has features of Additional Headers in the `Mail` section. In that you just need to write the email's header inside the Additional headers textbox in `Mail`(Second Tab) section.

Put this inside the Additional Headers textbox.

`Cc: [friend1-email], [friend2-email], [friend3-email], [friend4-email], [friend5-email]`

[image]

OR

You can alter the email header data by hooks `wpcf7_before_send_mail` try below code.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','dynamic_addcc');

function dynamic_addcc($WPCF7_ContactForm){

    // Check contact form id.
    if (33 == $WPCF7_ContactForm->id()) {

        $currentformInstance  = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
        $contactformsubmition = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ($contactformsubmition) {

            $cc_email = array();

            /* -------------- */
            // replace with your email field's names
            if(is_email($_POST['friend1-email'])){
                array_push($cc_email, $_POST['friend1-email']);
            }
            if(is_email($_POST['friend2-email'])){
                array_push($cc_email, $_POST['friend2-email']);
            }
            /* -------------- */

            // saparate all emails by comma.
            $cclist = implode(', ',$cc_email);

            $data = $contactformsubmition->get_posted_data();

            if (empty($data))
                return;

            $mail = $currentformInstance->prop('mail');

            if(!empty($cclist)){
                $mail['additional_headers'] = "Cc: $cclist";
            }

            // Save the email body
            $currentformInstance->set_properties(array(
                "mail" => $mail
            ));

            // return current cf7 instance
            return $currentformInstance;
        }
}
}
```

`wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook runs before email send, you can modify the form data.

Comment: This results in a syntax error

Comment: make as required those all email fields, @mikemike

Comment: But they arent required :(

Comment: all email inside `Cc:` should be present otherwise it will through error,

Comment: Yeah, hence my question

Comment: @mikemike I have updated my answer , replace with your contact form id and field's name.

Comment: what is the whole function supposed to return? As I can see from the code, It can only return something when `$contactformsubmition` is true. What if `$contactformsubmition` is not true